# Можно ли 2 раза повторять @link http:// в phpdocumentor

Tags: php, java

можно ли так писать?

```
/**
 *
 * @link http://www
 * @link http://www
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Вполне живой пример:

```
/**
 * мой принт
 * @param string $s
 * @link www.ya.ru
 * @link www.google.com
 */

function my_print($s)
{
    print $s."\n";
}
```

В нетбинс отработал нормально. Правда, как другие программы среагируют на такое не скажу.

Answer (score 0):

Простите, я ошибался. [Почитайте](http://habrahabr.ru/post/18326/)

Comment: это точно?

Comment: Это не так.

Comment: @Алексей Скляр может вы хотели сказать что так делать не хорошо? Хотя это тоже требует обоснования, как и ваш ответ.